# write select query for the below requirement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation, sql-like

This is my `users` table:

http://ezinfotec.com/Capture.PNG

I need to select all rows those are not contain 2 in except column. How to write a query for this using php & Mysql.

The result i expect for this query is only return last row only.

Thank you.

Comment: what. have. you. tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store comma separated values in your table, it's very bad practice, nevertheless you can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  users
WHERE 
  NOT FIND_IN_SET('2', except)
```

Comment: can you please tell me why we should not store comma separate value in table? just want to know

Comment: Because you need an additional work to make them in readable or workable format. THat's why MySQL is relational database, and you can use the well-known relations e.g. many to many

Comment: There's [this comprehensive SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574) about storing comma separate values in a columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(',', except, ',') NOT LIKE '%,2,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.except NOT LIKE '%,2%'
OR table.except NOT LIKE '%2,%';
```